# what will happen in NodeJs if I will run while(1){}

Tags: node.js

```
while(1){

}
```

**What will happen in nodejs if i will run the above code. will it block the nodeJs. if yes please explain how. because  nodejs is single threaded.

and can nodejs will ever
**

Answer (score 0):

I don't want explain about your code. I suggest you to try first. But may be your question about how to handle asynchronous which is nodejs is non-blocking I/O model and asynchronous.

You can handle using callback, promise or async await.

I will try using async await in this code bellow :

```
app.get('/getdatafromdatabase' async (req, res) => {
 try{
   const getData = await Schema.findById(req.body.id); //getdata from database
   console.log(getData);

   //if you not using await,console.log will return undifined
 } catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
 }
})
```